# postgres - cannot create collation

Tags: postgresql, debian, locale, collation

I have a postgres 9.2 database running on debian wheezy. If I execute in pgadmin:

```
CREATE COLLATION en ( LOCALE = 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

I get the following error message.

```
ERROR:  could not create locale "en_US.UTF-8": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
DETAIL:  The operating system could not find any locale data for the locale name "en_US.UTF-8".
```

I already configured locals on that machine and restarted postgres:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  tr_TR.UTF-8... done
```

But the error is still there. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: you may need to restart the postgres service

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that PostgreSQL uses operating system locales and collation orders.

On Debian, you need to run the following to add the locale:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then once en_US.UTF-8 is there it should work.